# Поломалась студия, все горит красным, но проект собирается и работает. Как исправить?

Tags: android, android-studio

Запустил студию и вижу такую картину, учитывая что все классы поломаны и все горит красным - проект собирается и работает. Помогите исправить. `Invalidate` не помогает. Вместо классов вообще куски разметки... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Все заработало корректно после удаления папки кэша Студии

C: \ Users \ admin.AndroidStudio3.3 \ система \ кэш